# How do I change the font colours for grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, fonts, colors, desktop-background

I managed to change the background on the boot screen and now I need to set the font colours to something I can read. I've been lurking around the Ubuntu Forums and the Ask site and I've also tried with the `grub-customizer` with no luck. All I need is the right code for grub file.

Here's a copy of my current grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/autumn/Pictures/grub/suckng.jpg"

menu_color_normal=black/black
menu_color_highlight=yellow/dark-gray
color_normal=black/black
color_higlight=black/black
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem in ubuntu 13.10 with grub-customizer.  In my case it was caused by reverting to the default debian theme, which made the image appear in the background, but all text was grey.  I solved it by editing the 05_debian_theme file found in /etc/grub.d/

$    `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

Find where it reads:

```
if [ -z "${2}" ] && [ -z "${3}" ]; then
        echo "  true"
fi
```

Change to:

```
if [ -z "${2}" ] && [ -z "${3}" ]; then
    echo "  true"
    echo "    set color_highlight=light-blue/black"
    echo "    set color_normal=white/black"
fi
```

Replace the colours with that of your choosing, remembering grub treats 'black' as transparent.  Then run the following and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that does not solve it for you go go back and edit the theme as mentioned above. You will see a section:

```
set_default_theme(){
case $GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR in
    Ubuntu|Kubuntu)
        # Set a monochromatic theme for Ubuntu.
        echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=white/black"
        echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=light-blue/black"

        if [ -e /lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub ]; then
            sed "s/^/${1}/" /lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        # Set the traditional Debian blue theme.
        echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=white/black"
        echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=light-blue/black"
        ;;
```

Change the colours to what you require then update-grub, reboot.

Good luck, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution: /etc/grub.d/06_local_colors

The problem is that update-grub recreates your grub.cfg. The usual way to configure update-grub in Ubuntu is to edit /etc/default/grub, but unfortunately text colors are not yet supported.

We will use a lower level method: create a script in /etc/grub.d/ which will output the lines we want in the grub.cfg files. We use the name `06_local_colors` so that it will run after 05_debian_theme and override the color choices.

There are three easy steps.

### Step 1. `sudo editor /etc/grub.d/06_local_colors`

Paste in this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/grub.d/06_local_colors
# Override foreground/background colors with local admin's choices.  
#
# Note: be sure to chmod +x this file or it will not be used.
# After editing this file, run update-grub.
set -e
echo "Overriding foreground/background text colors ($0)" >&2

echo "${1}set color_normal=light-gray/black"
echo "${1}set color_highlight=black/light-gray"

# Set these if you'd like the menu options to be different than other text
echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=light-gray/black"
echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray"

# NOTES

# Colors: red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, brown, light-gray, black
#
# Foreground has additional colors available:
#
#         light-red, light-green, light-blue
#         light-cyan, light-magenta, yellow, white, dark-gray

# Text background of "black" is transparent when a background image exists.
# (GRUB_BACKGROUND in /etc/default/grub).

# To change the font face and size, set GRUB_FONT in /etc/default/grub 
# to point to a .pf2 file crated by grub-mkfont.
# 
# sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2 --size=24 \
#           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

The script contains abundant notes so it should be quite simple to tweak.

### Step 2: `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/06_local_colors`

The file needs to be executable or it will not be used.

### Step 3: `sudo update-grub`

After update completes successfully, simply reboot to see what your new colors look like in GRUB.

---

##### Further reading

- [GNU GRUB Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf))

  - [color_normal](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/color_005fnormal.html#color_005fnormal) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf#color_normal))
    , [color_highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/color_005fhighlight.html#color_005fhighlight) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf#color_highlight))
  - [menu_color_normal](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/menu_005fcolor_005fnormal.html#menu_005fcolor_005fnormal) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf#menu_color_normal))
    , [menu_color_highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/menu_005fcolor_005fhighlight.html#menu_005fcolor_005fhighlight) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf#menu_color_highlight))
  - [GRUB Configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) ([PDF](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf#Configuration))
- [Man update-grub](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/update-grub.8.html)

##### Side note: Why not 05_debian_themes?

While it is possible to edit the system file `05_debian_theme`, as described in other answers, it is a bad idea. That file can may need to be overwritten when the system is updated.