# Change font colors in Grub2

Tags: grub2, customization

I can't get the font colors to change at all; the only thing I've managed to accomplish is getting a custom background on the Grub screen.

I tried `grub-customizer` but that doesn't work.
I tried what was suggested here: [How do I change the font colours for grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433839/how-do-i-change-the-font-colours-for-grub)
but that doesn't work.

Comment: Some info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: @oldfred I tried that--and it still didn't work. Specifically, I added the font colors to where that article said to.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Grub Customizer didn't work for me as well in the latest Mint. I was only able to change the image background. Here is how to change font colors easily:

In Grub customizer, go to `File > Change environment`

In the dialog that opens check the `CFG_DIR` line to know where is the grub config directory for your system. In my case it shows:

`CFG_DIR: /etc/grub.d`

Open your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in read only mode. At the top of the file you will see this warning:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

This is exactly what grub customizer does, it makes the `grub.cfg` from the templates you have in `CFG_DIR`.

Search in `grub.cfg` for this text: "set menu_color_normal"

Chances are that this line appears in a couple of places. Pick the one closest to the end of the file that is not inside an if. For instance, this one not:

```
if background_image /boot/grub/splash.png; then
    true
else
    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
fi
```

It will be something like this one:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/06_mint_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/06_mint_theme ###
```

See the begin and end tags around it? That is the template from where grub customizer is obtaining the font color config. And yes, it totally ignores what you set in the GUI. In my case, it is `/etc/grub.d/06_mint_theme` as I'm on a Mint distro. In your case it might have another name in the form `XX_something_theme`.

The easiest way of having your colors show up is:

1. Open the `/etc/grub.d` directory as root
2. Edit the `XX_something_theme` file and change the colors to your liking. There are 3 colors to tune:
   `menu_color_highlight`: highlighted menu entry and its background.
   `menu_color_normal`: normal menu entries and background. Also the box border.
   `color_normal`: text and background outside of box (title and bottom help).

The possible colors are {black, blue, brown, cyan, dark-gray, green, light-cyan, light-blue, light-green, light-gray, light-magenta, light-red, magenta, red, white, yellow}. Remember black means transparent for grub. Save the file.

3. Open Grub customizer
4. Make some changes to the colors (it doesn't mind which ones you pick, they will be ignored) and click save.

At that moment the colors you edited in the template will be appended into the definitive `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. Open this file in read only mode again to make sure.

Reference: [Grub2/Displays - Community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays)

Answer (score 0):

Please explain a bit, what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Whenever you edit your grub file, you'll need to enter the following command on a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Please do that and post back if it worked or not.

Also, when you say grub-customizer doesn't work, what do you mean? Did you manage to install it? Please enter the following commands before trying to install grub-customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

If you've managed to install grub-customizer, please ignore the previous set of commands.

Comment: The colors of the highlight/font color doesn't change--it stays whatever is default (which I this is light gray highlight with white font).

Grub Customizer doesn't manage to change the font colors, too. I have it installed, yes.

I've made sure I've done everything correctly--and I have. If it was as simple as `sudo update-grub`, I would have figured it out. :|